# Net name requirement for PCB design on upverter

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, layout

I am using [Upverter](https://upverter.com/) to do my PCB design. Whenever I have 3 or more connections on a net, it shows me a warning saying that I need to explicitly name it.[image: upverter net warning eg]
[image]

I would like to know if this is just a quirk of Upverter or it is some industry standard to name nets with 3 or more connections. In addition to that, is there an industry convention on how to name nets?

Answer (score 2):

That naming  requirement must be a quirk of Upverter.  I haven't seen such a requirement in the CAD systems I've used (Protel, Altium, KiCAD), or seen any mention it in other systems.

Comment: Agree.  All the schematic capture tools I've seen or used will automatically assign a name to any net, regardless of the number of nodes, if the user does not assign one.